# How to unlock Bitlocker encrypted partitions for backup?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, backup, encryption, windows-11

Since the release of Windows 11, it seems that these days, computer manufacturers (I've noticed both in HP and Dell computers) have Bitlocker Device Encryption turned on by default.

That creates major inconveniences for users who want to backup a partition. As you can see in the Macrium Reflect screenshot below. My 3 data partitions (C,D, and E) are locked by Bitlocker. I wanted to image my C drive and store the image file to my E drive. I do have the 48-digit unlock keys, but I can't find a place to enter those keys in the Macrium backup environment. I've also tried the Dell backup software from the BIOS. The issue with Bitlocker lock creeps up as well. Does anyone know how to unlock partitions in a backup environment (preferably Macrium Reflect) so that one can continue with the backup?

[image]

Comment: "Since the release of Windows 11, it seems that these days, computer manufacturers (I've noticed both in HP and Dell computers) have Blocker Device Encryption turned on by default." - Device Encryption != BitLocker.  Device Encryption is a requirement on Windows tablets and has been a requirement for the better part of 5 years.  However, in your case, the device in question does indeed have BitLocker enabled. "Does anyone know how to unlock partitions …" - I would suspend BitLocker Protection, or a better solution, create a 1:1 clone of the drive and store the recovery key on a separate disk.

Comment: Please when creating screen shots use the built-in functions of Windows and not a smartphone. The screenshot is barely readable

Answer (score 1):

The Macrium Reflect support article
[BitLocker Restore/Clone Outcomes](https://knowledgebase.macrium.com/display/KNOW80/BitLocker+Restore+Outcomes)
lists two possibilities:

1. The partitions to backup are mounted and unlocked before the
   backup, so the backup image is unencrypted
2. The partitions are backed up in a locked format and restored in
   the same state.

In both scenarios, Macrium Reflect does not need the Bitlocker
unlock key.

You will find more details inside the above article.

Comment: Thanks harrymc! You've provided answers to my posts numerous times, thank you for your help! Did you have experience with Macrium Reflect personally or you searched on Google using "site:macrium.com Bitlocker" as your keyword? I currently only search on Google without the "site:" function when I do research. You've always been able to provide good answers to my questions. I want to improve my research skills on IT topics. I'm just wondering if the "site:" function on Google search is what you use when doing research on questions like mine. Thanks!

Comment: No, I prefer AOMEI. I knew the basic answer already, so I was just looking for a reference that will allow me to write a short answer and give a link...